# Best way of displaying text on each UICollectionViewCell Item?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have jsonData in the below format.

```
 [
  {
        "player": "Gary Kirsten",
        "opp": "UAE",
        "runs": "188*",
        "balls": "159",
        "s/r": "118.23",
        "4s": "13",
        "6s": "4",
        "count": "7"
  }
]
```

I have created a class which can hold all this JSON info.

```
class Highest_Individual_Score: NSObject {

var player: String!
var opp: String!
var runs: String!
var balls: String!
var strikeRate: String!
var fours: String!
var sixes: String!
var count: String!

init(player: String!, opp: String, runs: String, balls: String, strikeRate: String, fours: String, sixes: String, count: String) {
    self.player = player
    self.opp = opp
    self.runs = runs
    self.balls = balls
    self.strikeRate = strikeRate
    self.fours = fours
    self.sixes = sixes
    self.count = count
  }
}
```

I am holding the json data in an array like this.

```
var highestIndividualScores = [Highest_Individual_Score]()
```

I am parsing my jsonData and i am filling my `highestIndividualScores` Array.

Now I have created `customCollectionView` by subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout` which can be scrollable in both directions.

my customCollectionView look exactly like below image.

[image: customCollectionView]

Now I am using the below code to return the number of sections in collectionView.

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return highestIndividualScores.count
}
```

Below code returns the number of items in each section.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(highestIndividualScores[section].count)!
}
```

I am having problems displaying all this information in  my `collectionView(UICollectionView, cellForItemAt: IndexPath)`

I want to show data in the format below.

[image]

***Can somebody tell me how I can show data in the above format?***

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }

    //HOW TO DISPLAY DATA HERE? IT SHOULD BE IN A SUCH A WAY THAT IF I ADD ONE MORE COLUMN TO MY MODEL THIS LOGIC SHOULD NOT CHANGE?
    cell.titleLabel.text = "\(indexPath.section) && \(indexPath.row)"

    return cell
}
```

***UPDATE***

***I am using below code to get data in desired format. What is the better way of doing displaying data in desired format?***

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Player"
        case 1:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Opp"
        case 2:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Runs"
        case 3:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Balls"
        case 4:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Strike Rate"
        case 5:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Fours"
        case 6:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Sixes"
        default: break
        }
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.titleLabel.text = highestIndividualScores[indexPath.section].player
        case 1:
            cell.titleLabel.text = highestIndividualScores[indexPath.section].opp
        case 2:
            cell.titleLabel.text = highestIndividualScores[indexPath.section].runs
        case 3:
            cell.titleLabel.text = highestIndividualScores[indexPath.section].balls
        case 4:
            cell.titleLabel.text = highestIndividualScores[indexPath.section].strikeRate
        case 5:
            cell.titleLabel.text = highestIndividualScores[indexPath.section].fours
        case 6:
            cell.titleLabel.text = highestIndividualScores[indexPath.section].sixes
        default: break
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Below is the image for reference.

[image]

Comment: I would use a `UITableView` instead and create  a tableViewCell representing a row.

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick response. i already have my collectionView. my problem is configuring cell to display the data as i have shown in above image.

Comment: Understood. Recommendation does not change though. Good luck!

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the output you are getting?

Comment: @PGDev i updated my question please check.